# Pattern matching a file in a specific directory that may be nested inside that directory

Tags: java, regex, reflections

I'm using [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library.

Trying to match a page with ID `MyPage` inside a directory called `demo` e.g:

```
com/org/apps/demo/view/{any}/{number}/{of}/{dirs}/MyPage.xml
or
com/org/apps/demo/view/{dir}/MyPage.xml
or
com/org/apps/demo/view/MyPage.xml
```

This is the pattern I thought would match the path:

```
reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*demo.*MyPage.xml"))
```

But it returns 0 results.

Init of Reflections:

```
Reflections reflections =
        new Reflections(
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.org"))
                .setScanners(new ResourcesScanner()));

String pageId = "MyPage";

Set<String> pages = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*demo.*MyPage.xml"))
```

`pages` then contains 0 elements.

Whereas if I use something like. (single wildcard):

```
Set<String> pages = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*MyPage.xml"))
```

`pages` then contains 1 element, as expected.

```
com/org/apps/demo/view/subdir/MyPage.xml
```

Comment: I don't know what is the issue with the reflections library but I am certain that your regex is too loose. You would want `(?:^|.*\/)demo\/(?:.+\/)?MyPage\.xml` or else `com/org/apps/demonstration/view/MyPage.xml` and `com/org/apps/demo/view/MyPage-xml` would match

Answer (score 0):

You can give this pattern a try, to match the full paths:

```
^com/org/apps/demo/view/(?:[^/]+/)*MyPage[.]xml$
```